# Backend I/O error

Tags: postgresql

When i am running my we application i am getting following error any one can help me to get rid of it.

i am using jdk 1.6,tomcat 6.0,windows Xp

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:283)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:479)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:353)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:252)
        at com.i10n.db.dao.TripDetailsDaoImpl.getActiveTripDetailsWithLiveStatusForTheUser(TripDetailsDaoImpl.java:52)
        at com.i10n.db.dao.TripDetailsDaoImpl.getActiveTripDetailsWithLiveStatusForTheUser(TripDetailsDaoImpl.java:37)
        at com.i10n.fleet.providers.mock.managers.DriverManager.parseDataset(DriverManager.java:56)
        at com.i10n.fleet.providers.mock.managers.DriverManager.getData(DriverManager.java:39)
        at com.i10n.fleet.providers.mock.ReportsDataProvider.getDataset(ReportsDataProvider.java:61)
        at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.ViewController.handleRequest(ViewController.java:58)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:793)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:431)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.flush(PGStream.java:508)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendSync(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1107)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:256)
        ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your postgres process crashed, or something in your network is broken and kills connection. Check the postgres logs.

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2004-12/msg00010.php) from 2004 may be useful in solving the problem.